# Contact data not visible in ListManager list upon submitting data using "MVC Subscription form" of EXM 3.4

Tags: exm, list-manager

I have Sitecore 8.2 initial, integrated with EXM 3.4. I am using the "MVC subscription form" for adding an email ID into an already created contact list. Upon submitting the email ID, I can see a contact with the `SMTPAddress` field getting created in MongoDB. However, I am not able to see the same contact in the configured list within the List Manager.

Is there any other configuration necessary in order to see the contact in the List Manager?

Answer (score 2):

EXM uses a double opt-in process, so a contact will not be subscribed to a list before confirming subscription, see [The EXM double opt-in process](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/subscription_management/configuring/the_exm_double_optin_process). In short:

1. Contact subscribes to a list using the [EXM ClientAPI](https://doc.sitecore.net/email%20experience%20manager/subscription%20management/the%20exm%20client%20api)
2. An email which contains a link to confirm the subscription, is sent to the contact
3. Contact clicks the link and is added to the list

As the contact is being created, and (I'm assuming) you're not seeing any errors, I believe you simply need to confirm the subscription, after which you will see the contact in the list.

In addition to this, I recommend that you disable list locking. If you don't, you are very likely to see problems when contacts subscribe/unsubscribe. To do so, you simply need to enable the following configuration file on your CM instance:

```
App_Config\Include\ListManagement\Sitecore.ListManagement.DisableListLocking.config
```

More details about list locking can be found in the [release notes for 8.2 update 2](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update2/Release%20Notes)

Answer (score 0):

For how long did you wait? It will take a while to appear...

First, the information will be saved in the contact (session), once the session times out, it will be sent to Mongo, and then an aggregation process executed periodically will send the information to the indexes. Once the update reaches the index, then it will appear in the list manager.
As you can see, depending on your configuration it could take easili even more than 30' to appear.